# Comparing number in formatted string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `PolicyNo` column in my table in MySQL with a format like this:

```
XXXX-000000
```

A four capital-case **characters** followed by a **dash** and a six digit **number**.

The six digit number is incremental, adding `1` for the next row, and the the four characters is always the same for all rows. The `PolicyNo` column is unique with a type of `varchar(11)`.

If ordered, it will look like this:

```
XXXX-000001
XXXX-000002
XXXX-000003
...
```

Now I want to get all `PolicyNo` whose number is greater than a specified number.

For example: Retrieve all `PolicyNo` greater than `'XXXX-000100'`:

```
XXXX-000101
XXXX-000102
XXXX-000103
...
```

I test this query and it works fine, but I just didn't know if it is really *safe* to do such:

```
SELECT  'XXXX-000099' > 'XXXX-000098'
    ,   'XXXX-000099' > 'XXXX-000100'
    ,   'XXXX-000099' > 'XXXX-000101'

Result:
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| 'XXXX-000099' > 'XXXX-000098' | 'XXXX-000099' > 'XXXX-000100' | 'XXXX-000099' > 'XXXX-000101' |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|                             1 |                             0 |                             0 |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Is there any other way to do this or is it already OK to use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your numbers are zero padded, as long as the four letter prefix is the same and *always* the same length, then this should work as MySQL will do a lexicographical comparison.

Note that one less `0` in the padding will cause this to fail:

```
SET @policy1 = 'XXXX-00099';
SET @policy2 = 'XXXX-000598';
SELECT @policy1, @policy2, @policy1 > @policy2 AS comparison;
=========================================
> 'XXXX-00099', 'XXXX-000598', 1
```

If you need to truly compare the numbers at the end, you will need to parse them out and cast them:

```
SET @policy1 = 'XXXX-00099';
SET @policy2 = 'XXXX-000598';
SELECT @policy1, @policy2, 
   CONVERT(SUBSTRING(@policy2, INSTR(@policy2, '-')+1), UNSIGNED) >
   CONVERT(SUBSTRING(@policy2, INSTR(@policy2, '-')+1), UNSIGNED) AS comparison;
=========================================
> 'XXXX-00099', 'XXXX-000598', 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use SUBSTRING function provided by MySQL, like the following query.

> **SELECT count(*) FROM Table1  where substring(policyNo,6)>YOUR_RANGE;**

here 6 is passed as the 6 digit number start from 6th position And if you do want to pass initial 4 charecter as well then you can use following query. Here second where clause will take intial 4 letters from the policyNo.

**SELECT count(*) FROM Table1  where substring(policyNo,6)>YOUR_RANGE AND substring(policyNo,1,4) = 'ABCD'**